# Use multiple service or do all operations in single service which is preferable?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, sockets

I am developing one socket based application in which i am continuously updating the status of room like how many lights are on and off. I have 7 this kind of rooms and i need to update the status for each room.

So my question is should i created a separate service for each room or i should perform all operation in single service ?. which way would be the more convenient as far as performance is concerned.

Here is my Service class for Single room.

```
public class UpdateUiService extends Service 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        try {
            s = new Socket("192.168.1.19,502);
            i = s.getInputStream();
            o = s.getOutputStream();
            System.out.println("connected");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

    }

    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();
            handler.postDelayed(this, Integer.parseInt(interval_dinning));
        }
    };

    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        try {
            byte[] data1 = new byte[1024], packet1 = 
            { 
                (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00, 
                (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x06, 
                (byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x01,(byte) 0x00,
                (byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x19
            };

            o.write(packet1);
            i.read(data1, 0, 1024);

            byte_to_hex = ConversionMethods.bytesToHex(data1).substring(18, 26);

            char[] arr = byte_to_hex.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i += 2) {
                char temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
                arr[i + 1] = temp;
            }

            swapped_result = new String(arr);
            result = ConversionMethods.hexStringToNBitBinary(swapped_result, 32);
            int counter_ = 0;
            for( int i=0; i<result.length(); i++ ) 
            {
                if( result.charAt(i) == '1' )
                {
                    counter_++;        
                }  
            }
            status=Integer.toString(counter_);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        intent.putExtra("counter", String.valueOf(++counter));
        intent.putExtra("status", status);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    } 
}
```

And i am starting this service and getting broadcasted intent in activity where i want to show this values. here is the reference link to [update UI from background service](http://www.websmithing.com/2011/02/01/how-to-update-the-ui-in-an-android-activity-using-data-from-a-background-service/).

How do i achieve this using multithreading. my ultimate goal is to read socket and get the status as a result that's it.

Please point me to a right direction.Any suggestion and idea will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What are you asking for? How to change you service for connecting to different remote addresses?

Comment: @Jin35 i have diffrent rooms and each room is connected using different IPs, so i want to know the status of different rooms, above implemetation is for only single room. if i change the ip it will give me the status of other room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Questions**

a) It's not obvious from your code what is starting your service. Is it started once or multiple times.

Based on current code, it looks like it will send something to ip, read result, send one broadcast and that's it.

So, the question, do you need to update lights status just once or you need to update them constantly/periodically?

**Ideas**

a) In the case, if you need to update lights statuses just once and it's triggered from UI and updates UI, you will be much better off with [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) which is specifically designed for this.

And it's up to you whether you want to have 7 concurrent AsyncTask's (if you want to update lights status in parallel) or you can have one AsyncTask which will update lights status serially and report back to UI thread after each of lights were updated.

b) In the case, if you need continuously track lights status then you are better off with a service. However, you need to have a long running thread in this service. So, you should start a thread in onStart.

Generally, it should (let say once in 10 seconds) invoke some method which will cause all communication and so on.

At that method, you can spur X threads (one for each room) and in these threads do all your operations (write to socket, read, parse and etc) or you can execute all of these actions within this first thread. You have here the same choice as with AsyncTask to do this in parallel or serially.

c) Also, you may want to keep all sockets alive and reused them to not reconnect each 5 seconds when you need to update lights status.

**General comments**

a) You are using onStart() which is deprecated. You should be using onStartCommand()

b) I understand that it could be a prototype, but this piece of code which you showed have quite low quality. If you won't clean it up, you will have a lot of bugs to chase in the future:

You have in code:

- a lot of magic numbers
- misnamed functions (like DisplayLoggingInfo, which doesn't display anything, but rather read/write socket, do some conversion and send broadcasts)
- long methods (DisplayLoggingInfo)

*Update 1*

Here is the sample app for you.
Please be aware, this is a prototype. You may be interested to add more checks, separate it to more classes and so on.

MyService.java

```
package com.example.servicesample;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import java.lang.Thread;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

public class MyService extends Service implements Runnable {
    public static final String ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST = "com.example.room_status_broadcast";
    public static final String ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST_EXTRA_ROOM_NUMBER = "roomnumber";
    public static final String ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST_EXTRA_STATUS = "status";

    static final int NUM_ROOMS = 7;
    static final int TIME_FOR_A_REST = 5000; //ms

    Thread mThread = null;
    Boolean mRunning = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        start();

        return  START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        stop();
    }

    private synchronized void start()
    {
        if (mThread != null)
            return;

        mRunning = true;
        mThread = new Thread(this);
        mThread.start();
    }

    private synchronized void stop()
    {
        if (mThread == null)
            return;

        mRunning = true;

        try
        {
            mThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        mThread = null;
    }


    public void run()
    {
        while (mRunning)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ROOMS; i++)
                updateRoomStatus(i);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(TIME_FOR_A_REST);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}             
        }
    }

    Boolean getRoomStatus(int roomNumber)
    {
        // Do real communication here (instea of just assigning true)
        // It makes sense to move all communication to a separate class from here
        Boolean newRoomStatus = true;

        return newRoomStatus;
    }

    void updateRoomStatus(int roomNumber)
    {
        Boolean newRoomStatus = getRoomStatus(roomNumber);
        broadcastRoomStatus(roomNumber, newRoomStatus);
    }

    void broadcastRoomStatus(int roomNumber, Boolean newRoomStatus)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST_EXTRA_ROOM_NUMBER, roomNumber);
        intent.putExtra(ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST_EXTRA_STATUS, newRoomStatus);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

MyActivity.java

```
package com.example.servicesample;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import com.example.servicesample.MyService;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private IntentFilter mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter(MyService.ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST);


    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            MainActivity.this.receivedBroadcast(intent);       
        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startMyService();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
        return true;
    }   

    void startMyService()
    {
        // You can move this code to be executed on a button click or something else
        // It will start a service
        startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
    }   

    @Override
    protected void onResume()
    {
        super.onResume();

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);

        super.onPause();
    }   

     private void receivedBroadcast(Intent i) {
         Integer roomNumber = i.getIntExtra(MyService.ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST_EXTRA_ROOM_NUMBER, 0);
        Boolean roomStatus = i.getBooleanExtra(MyService.ROOM_STATUS_BROADCAST_EXTRA_STATUS, false);

        // Let's do here whatever we want with received status (as example, update UI)
        Log.d("SomeTag", "Room number "+roomNumber.toString() + " got new status " + roomStatus.toString());
     }  

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.servicesample"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.servicesample.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".MyService"/>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: First of all Thanks for your answer, my current code will give me status for only single room and i want 7 this kind of room and i want status of all rooms which is connected using different ip addresses. And yes i want to do this check constantly.

Comment: @juned: Then go with a thread(or multiple threads) in Service (Idea b).

Comment: yeah, but i think the same but how do i implement this using multi threading, can you give me simple example to read the result which can be used in any activity ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in this should i put my socket related task in `getroomstatus()` method ?

Comment: Yes. You should put your communication in getroomstatus() method. However, in longer term, I would recommend to create a separate class which does all communications and just call some methods of this class from getroomstatus method.

Comment: i am facing a problem with this `getroomstatus()` method. i have just created different class to get status and in this method i am calling only this two lines `roomStatus = new ReadRoomStatus(ip); String status = roomStatus.readStatus();` but the problem is it shows me the result only 11 times after that thread goes in sleep. why this happens ?

Comment: @juned: Have you seen line:  Thread.sleep(TIME_FOR_A_REST); I added it specifically, so when status read for each room, thread will pause a little bit and only after this pause start reading again. If you don't have pause, it will run constantly and it may consume too much power. You may comment it out or change the value.

Comment: yeah i have see this but if i just print some log messages instead of calling above two lines then its working awesome,it runs continuously after interval specified in TIME_FOR_A_REST value. here is my class [ReadRoomStatus](http://paste.ubuntu.com/5633252/). you may check if there is any problem. THanks again

Comment: my problem is got solved there was a some other issue, your code is absolutely fine :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the performance between having one `Service` for each room, or one `Service` for all rooms - I would consider 7 services very excessive. One thing you need to understand is that a `Service` is not a new `Thread`. Services run on the same thread as your `Activity`. What you will want to do is have one Service that listens for connections on multiple sockets, then create a new thread for each connection (room) established. As others have suggested, an `AsyncTask` is a great way to handle a background process, because it provides callbacks to the main thread. It does have limitations, however - such as the number of threads it can handle. If we are talking one thread per room - this should not be a problem. If that is not the case, consider using a blocking thread for each room connection.